# django - TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, django

Hello I added a field to a model and when I try to do `migrate` in terminal it give me this error, does anyone know what this might be?

=========================================================================

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 454, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 199, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_fields=[(old_field, new_field)])
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 137, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(temp_model)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 212, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 124, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 187, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 627, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1290, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1269, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1171, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1228, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/Users/Derek/.virtualenvs/tasks/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 70, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

model.py

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(choices=TITLE_CHOICES, max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    currently_using_sms = models.CharField(choices=CURRENTLY_USING_SMS, default='',  max_length=30)
    services_interested_in = models.ManyToManyField(Services)
    phone_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20, default='')
    mobile_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=11, default='')
    email = models.EmailField(blank='True', default='')
    best_day_to_contact = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    assign_to = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    lead_source = models.ForeignKey(LeadSource, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=LEAD_STATUS, max_length=100, default='1')
```

Comment: well. `value` is not a string or buffer, which `datetime_re.match` is expecting. What's the code that it's executed in, and/or what's the value being passed to that function that's causing the error?

Comment: post your model code

Comment: @oke1: can you please post your models.py class over here.

Comment: I have the same issue before. I tried `default=False` but it doesn't make any change. Then I add `default=timezone.now`, It works correctly. Only problem is date field are not displayed in admin section.

Answer (score 9):

Django’s `DateTimeField` generally works with Python `datetime` and `date` objects, but [has an undocumented feature of being able to automatically parse strings into `datetime` objects](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1420). In your `DateTimeField` declaration, you had

```
default=False
```

which is neither `datetime` nor `date`. Thus, Django tries to parse it automatically for you. Failing to do so, it emits the cryptic message.

Depending on your specific need, you should either replace, or just remove the `default=False` argument.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have an error in `default=False` of the following line:

```
    completion_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True, default=False)
```

`False` is not a valid date `default` expects. Use `default=datetime.now` instead.

Comment: yes i have the same issue before. i tried `default=False` it doesn't make any change. then i add `default=timezone.now` then its work correctly. only problem is date field are not display in admin section.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue before. I tried default=False but it doesn't make any change. Then I add default=timezone.now, It works correctly. Only problem is date field are not displayed in admin section.

change this field:

```
best_day_to_contact = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True)
```

to this field:

```
from django.utils import timezone
best_day_to_contact = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I think maybe your problem will fix with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Example Model */     

class user(models.Model):
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

/*When you generate migrations file then it will add (default=1)
*Remove default=1
*field=models.DateField(default=1, auto_now_add=True),
*To 
*field=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

*Then do sqlmigrate or migrate.  
*/
```

Comment: It helped me to solve the the problem with Django commands with DateTime, by adding auto_now_add=True and removing the default. Thank you

Comment: Thanks and welcome. I tried and executed this way and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to weigh in, as this issue gave me a big headache. Django got caught on a bad migration for me after I added a models.DateField. It didn't fix itself until I deleted all migrations and reran makemigrations.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you might be required to go back to your text editor and delete all migrations. It usually happens when django land in bad migrations. After that re-do new migrations. Hope this will solve your problem